# How do I keep all ul and li's under a parent li:selected, but remove other navigation items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to only keep the UL & LIs under the selected parent, but remove any others that occur before or after.

For example, given:

```
<ul id="fruit">
    <li class="selected"> Red </li>
        <ul> Sweet </ul>
            <li> Cherry </li>
            <li> Apple </li>
        <ul> Tart </ul>
    <li> Yellow <li>
    <li> Green </li>
```

I need:

```
    <li class="selected"> Red </li>
        <ul> Sweet </ul>
            <li> Cherry </li>
            <li> Apple </li>
        <ul> Tart </ul>
```

I have tried $(".fruit li:not(.selected)"); however that removes all the children li and ul included. I also tried

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.s4-ql li').each(function(){
    if($(this).parent.attr('selected') == 'selected'){
    $(this).css("display", "initial");
    }
else {
  $(this).css("display", "none");

}
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you cannot have a `ul` as a child of a `ul`, only `li`

Comment: Further to Rory's comment, you certainly can't have unenclosed strings `"Sweet"` as a child of an already-invalid `<ul>`. Correct your HTML, and *then* you might find that your JavaScript/jQuery works rather more accurately and predictably.

Comment: It was pseudo-code, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you correct your HTML to valid HTML like this:

```
<ul id="fruit">
    <li class="selected"> Red 
        <ul>
            <li> Sweet </li>
            <li> Cherry </li>
            <li> Apple </li>
            <li> Tart</li> 
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Yellow </li>
    <li> Green </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can detach your selected like this.

```
var $selected = $('#fruit').find('.selected').detach();
```

It's a simple remove() of the $('#fruit') from there and your selected is the part you wanted to keep.
https://jsfiddle.net/n25qbmLo/

It looks like your Sweet and Tart are subheaders so if that's true your HTML should be like this:

```
<ul id="fruit">
    <li class="selected"> Red 
        <ul>
          <li> Sweet 
              <ul>
                <li> Cherry </li>
                <li> Apple </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li> Tart</li> 
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Yellow </li>
    <li> Green </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n25qbmLo/2/

Comment: Do you need your Sweet and Tart to be a header? then you need to nest another UL for sweet.  I updated the answer to show this. Jiayou!